# How to clean concurrent map safely

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to solve a problem which seems quite common to me, but I could not find good solution for it.

In a very concurrent environment I need to release resources correctly when client session is destroyed. Here is input:

- I use `ConcurrentHashMap` to store all allocated resources, map is required here to index resources
- While session is being destroyed sometimes new resources are allocated from pending tasks, which I want ultimately deallocate as well

Here is my current solution:

```
while (!resourceMap.isEmpty()) {
    Map<Integer, Resource> toDestroy = new HashMap<>(resourceMap);
    for (Resource resource : toDestroy.values()) {
        resource.destroy();
    }
    resourceMap.keySet().removeAll(toDestroy.keySet());
}
```

Which exists only because `ConcurrentHashMap#values#iterator` does not always reflect concurrent puts to `resourceMap`. I do not like this code and would prefer queue-like code, but unfortunately `ConcurrentMap` does not provide anything like this:

```
while ((Map.Entry<String, Resource> entry = resourceMap.removeAny()) != null) {
    entry.value().destroy();
}
```

I am looking for solution which is similar to queue-like code above or any alternative approaches to this problem.

Comment: So whats the error or problem?

Comment: your current source code doesn't seem to work in some cases too, if I got it right, you stop when `resourceMap.isEmpty()`, but what if after that some delayed resource put itself there? you should know when your application is done producing resources and only then you can stop cleaning them.

Comment: @RuslanAkhundov true, and this is covered in my application, I am only concerned with this particular piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not like this code and would prefer queue-like code, but unfortunately ConcurrentMap does not provide anything like this ...

I would just use an iterator but then again I'm not a Java 8 fan.

```
while (!resourceMap.isEmpty()) {
    Iterator<Resource> iterator = resourceMap.values().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       Resource resource = iterator.next();
       iterator.remove();
       resource.destroy();
    }
}
```

It's important to note that there are race conditions in this model.  Someone could get the resource, go to use it, but at the same time it is being destroyed by this thread.

Comment: Accepting this answer, since it provides better memory management, no need to create extra HashMap. Thanks